# Small white grains on underside of spinach?

Tags: diagnosis, pests, spinach

What are these white grains on my spinach leaf?  What are they? Is it safe to it?

Not the big white thing (that's a hemp heart). I mean the little white grains lining the leafs veins...

Curious because now I'm not sure I want to eat this salad.

[image: white grains on spinach]

Answer (score 4):

These look like whitefly eggs. You should be fine to wash them off and eat the produce. Consider a horticultural oil as a treatment with an increase in aeration.

Answer (score 1):

Trichromes. totally normal spinach thing. i just learned about them.